# Having trouble getting Google Maps to display on my site.

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting my lat & long via:

```
$geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $g_location . '&sensor=true');
$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

I return the correct lat & long. So now I try to build my map:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCTQqh2ksk9ZTqSfx-_ki_lHj-q32kYIY8&sensor=false">    </script>
<script language="JavaScript">
 var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$lat?>, <?=$long?>),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);      
</script>
```

HTML:

```
div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Nothing is showing up. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your <`div id="map_canvas">` needs a size, (width and height) so,

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px;height:300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following.  You need to use `initialize()` in the onload function in the body as well

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>
```

Please refer to the google map playground examples

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#map_simple